# How can I make three columns my primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to learn how to match two files together. But I'm trying everythng for 5 hours now... And still no idea what to do.

The first file(600.000 rows) contains 4 columns:

```
Postal, Number, Houseletter, livingspace
```

The second file(7.000 rows) contains 4 columns:

```
Postal, Number, Houseletter, Furniturevalue
```

In my first file I have all the livingspaces from a big area and in my second file I have the Furniturevalue of a couple of adresses in that big area.

I want to add to the adresses in my second file the livingspaces from file 1.

So I imported the files in a database.

```
Table first file -> Space
Table second file -> Furniture
```

Now i'm trying to make Primary keys to the tables:

```
Primary key --> Postal, Number, Houseletter
```

But this doesn't work, because the columns are only unique when  Postal+Number+Houseletter, but not apart from each other.

Does anyone know the next step? What do I have to do to make this query work:

```
SELECT postal, number, houseletter, furniturevalue, livingspace
FROM space, furniture
WHERE ( space.postal = furniture.postal
AND     space.number = furniture.number
AND     space.houseletter = furniture.houseletter)
```

Im trying to make with this query a new view with `postal, number, houseletter, furniturevalue, livingspace' 
So data from two tables. 
But first I need a solution for my problem with the primary key.

Thanks for your help!

ps: Im using sql in phpmyadmin

Comment: what do you mean by `Primary key --> Postal, Number, Houseletter` did you try to make three primary keys or a composed primary key using the three columns ?

Comment: Did you try creating composite primary keys? And do you get any errors when you run your SQL?

Comment: You should realize what you are doing is the opposite of a 'best practice'.

Comment: No I just wanted to let you guys know that that are my primary keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE space ADD PRIMARY KEY(Postal, Number, Houseletter);
```

If a primary key *already exists* then you want to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE space DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(Postal, Number, Houseletter);
```

if you got duplicate PKs, you can try this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE space ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (Postal, Number, Houseletter );
```

This will drop all the duplicate rows. As an added benefit, future INSERTs that are duplicates will error out. As always, you may want to take a backup before running something like this

Second question, your query should look like this :

```
SELECT postal, number, houseletter, furniturevalue, livingspace
FROM space INNER JOIN furniture
ON ( space.postal = furniture.postal
AND     space.number = furniture.number
AND     space.houseletter = furniture.houseletter)
```

Comment: thanks! I did the first query but I got an error that some rows are double.. But Do you know to delete double rows?

Comment: Thanks I will try, I let you know!

Comment: Can you invite me for a chat? I have a view questions!

Comment: What do I have to type here? 'idx_name'

Comment: I got an error when quering this: ALTER IGNORE TABLE space ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (Postal, Number, Houseletter );
My error is:
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1391BR-19-' for key 'Adres_index'

Comment: you can add anything as per your convention like idx_tablename_xyz

Comment: Yes, this error will come up if you try inserting duplicate. This is what you wanted to eleminate duplicate entries I guess

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27193/discussion-between-warnerst-and-mayukh-roy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` to create a unique row per `(postal, number, houseletter)` combination.  An aggregate calculates the value of `livingspace` for that group.  This example picks the highest `livingspace` with the `max()` aggregate:

```
select  coalesce(space.postal, furniture.postal) as postal
,       coalesce(space.number, furniture.number) as number
,       coalesce(space.houseletter, furniture.houseletter) as houseletter
,       max(furniture.furniturevalue) as furniturevalue
,       max(space.livingspace) as livingspace
from    space
full outer join
        furniture
on      space.postal = furniture.postal
        and space.number = furniture.number
        and space.houseletter = furniture.houseletter
group by
        coalesce(space.postal, furniture.postal)
,       coalesce(space.number, furniture.number)
,       coalesce(space.houseletter, furniture.houseletter)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know!

Comment: I got this, when adding the primary keys:
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1391BR-19-' for key 'Adres_index'

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraintName> PRIMARY KEY (colA, colB, ..., colN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. You can use concat() to combine the columns together.

```
select (concat(s.Postal,' ',s.Number,' ',s.Houseletter)) as s.address,(concat(f.Postal,' ',f.Number,' ',f.Houseletter)) as f.address,s.*,f.* from space s,furniture f where s.address=f.address;
```