# INSERT query for unique records-Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a table like this

```
id | name | zip 
1  | abc  | 1234
2  | xyz  | 4321 
3  | asd  | 1234
```

I want to insert records such that the `id` and `name` when inserted may have the same value but if the value of `zip` is also same for that particular record it is not inserted. If not it should be inserted.

**eg:** I can insert another row with value for `id=1` and value for `name= abc` but if that record also has `zip=1234` it should not be inserted.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Add a unique key to those columns that need to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a check before inserting the row, for exmpale

```
select * from table where zip = @zip and name = @name and id = @id
```

if no rows return you can do the insert...

Comment: Thanks I feel so dumb now

Comment: you could also do the same in one insert query .. try this ... INSERT INTO table VALUES(zip, name, id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zip = zip, name = name, zip = zip

Answer (score 1):

Create two unique indexes:

```
create unique index idx_table_name_zip on table(name, zip)
create unique index idx_table_id_zip on table(id, zip)
```

The database will then guarantee the uniqueness you want to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Primary Key from **id, name and zip** combined

> ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, name, zip)

With this a row/record is marked duplicate if all the three columns are same otherwise it is a perfectly fine non-duplicate record.

check this for more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706765/how-can-i-make-three-columns-my-primary-key)